# firing onChange even if value didn't change

Tags: javascript

We have this select that's being used to navigate between various categories of links. "Dogs" takes the user to the dog links, "Cats" takes the user to the cat links, etc.

Here's the use case I can't quite get working:

1) The user selects "Dogs"

2) The user scrolls down a bit in the dog links

3) The user clicks "Dogs" again

At this point, I would like the page to scroll to the top of the dogs section, but instead, selecting "Dogs" a second time doesn't do anything, because the select's value hasn't changed and onChange never fires.

I should mention that we've banished onClick for accessibility concerns.

Comment: please show code you wrote for this

Comment: How about changing the `select.selectedIndex = 0`, post user selection?

Comment: @Arvind That would change the displayed value in the select, which isn't great.

Comment: How about using blur event? But user still has to click somewhere else after selecting same choice.

Comment: Using the blur event is no good idea. First, the user has to actually remove focus from the select for the action to happen. Second, if a user navigates the page with a keyboard, tabbing from element to element, the blur event is triggered for the select when the user just temporarily visits the select while navigating somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

From an accessibility perspective you would not want to rely entirely on the onClick event for this action ([WebAIM on the onClick event](https://webaim.org/techniques/javascript/eventhandlers#onclick)).

Yet as the article states, in the case of most modern browsers pressing the enter key on form control elements (including `<select>`) will trigger an onClick event.

The best way to polyfill this for older browsers is to look for a `keydown` event with the keycode `13` for the enter key.

I think the best solution for your case would be looking for `onChange`, `onClick`, and `keydown` (where enter has been pressed), then take action accordingly.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3wdtf9L/11/) for inspecting the events on a select element.